# does cURL work for some specified websites?

Tags: curl

Why the command

> $ curl www.facebook.com

does not work, while the command

> $ curl www.example.com

works ?? Is there any restriction with some of the websites, to get their source code via cURL

Answer (score 1):

When you have problems with curl, the first thing to try is the `--verbose` option, or its slightly less verbose cousin `--include`.

```
$ curl --include www.facebook.com
HTTP/1.1 302 forced.302
Location: https://www.facebook.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-FB-Debug: xJrxsrLiOuMwGBUSyUyXURhBdIcj/ZegnfeIReFcNxrtuMNv0+JivRudlLO4XIzq/Dy1CGgC14DUhCkrXUT3Rw==
Date: Sun, 14 Sep 2014 11:44:59 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

Now you can see that Facebook redirects you from `http://www.facebook.com/` to `https://www.facebook.com/`, because it really wants you to use encryption. When you request the new URL, you get the desired HTML code. You can make `curl` follow redirects automatically using the `--location` option.

This does the trick for Facebook, but with other sites you may hit other problems.

Some sites don’t like curl and other automated tools; they only want to talk to real Web browsers. They may respond with empty pages or errors like 403 Forbidden. If you really need to, you can work around this by replacing the [user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string with the `--user-agent` option—but please also make sure you don’t flood the site with requests, by inserting appropriate delays (generally tens of seconds) between them.

Some sites use the [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) technique in such a way that when you retrieve them with curl, you only see a skeleton of a page without interesting content, because all the real work is done in JavaScript. In this case you can either make out the AJAX requests and reproduce them with curl, or use a headless browser engine instead of the bare HTTP client that curl is.